# How can i return a formatted string from a rust macro

Tags: rust

I am trying to achieve something like this:

1. Construct an `error` message with some captured variables;
2. Log this `error` message;
3. Save and return this `error` message to user eventually;

Apparently this can be done in a few lines of code, but it is a bit tedious since i need this pattern heavily everywhere in my project, i mean like below:

```rust
let var_a = 233;
let err = format!("some custom error message, var_a: {}", var_a);

// Here i do the logging with the `tokio-rs/tracing` macros.
error!(err = %err, "some custom error message");

// The s_errs will be eventually showed to end users.
s_errs.append(err);
```

I am trying to achieve this with a macro which wraps the `tokio-rs/tracing` macros but return the constructed `err` message:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! log_usr_err {
    ($($arg:tt)+) => (
      error!($($arg)+)
      format!($($arg)+)
  );
}
```

so i can just use this macro in my project to simplify the coding a bit:

```rust
let err = log_usr_err!("some custom error message, {}", var_a = var_a);

// The s_errs will be eventually showed to end users.
s_errs.append(err);
```

but stuck at the compile error:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `format` and any following
```

How should i return the formatted string from my `log_urs_err!` macro?

Coz in the future in want to include the accurate `file!` info and the `line!` info also in my logs, thus i think via macro is the right direction to go, or there is some better approach?

Comment: Will it work if you add a semicolon after `error!($($arg)+)` macro invocation?

Comment: @Cerberus no... still the same error, and additionally i got a new warning which tells that i should not add the `;`  coz in future it will be an error: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79813 (actually it was the reason i removed the `;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just try and look at what the expanded code would look like in your case. Reiterating the code in question:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! log_usr_err {
    ($($arg:tt)+) => (
      error!($($arg)+)
      format!($($arg)+)
  );
}

let err = log_usr_err!("some custom error message, {}", var_a = var_a);
```

If we try to literally substitute the result of macro expansion, we'd get the following:

```
let err = error!("some custom error message, {}", var_a = var_a)
format!("some custom error message, {}", var_a = var_a);
```

This is obviously not valid Rust.

The problem is that your macro is currently written to expand to the list of *statements*, i.e. to some self-contained part of the code (of course, after adding the necessary semicolon between `error` and `format`). It can be, for example, a function body [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5735171e6e27e3bdd8ef139796b5c2d):

```
macro_rules! log_usr_err {
    ($($arg:tt)+) => (
      error!($($arg)+);
      format!($($arg)+)
  );
}

fn err() {
    log_usr_err!("test");
}
```

But you'd like to use this macro in *expression* position, i.e. to assign the value returned from it to the variable. For this, macro must expand to the expression, not to statements.

So, what to do? The change is, in fact, quite simple: a set of statements can be converted to expression by wrapping them in a block, since blocks are expressions:

```
macro_rules! log_usr_err {
    ($($arg:tt)+) => ({
        error!($($arg)+);
        format!($($arg)+)
    });
}
```

Note the extra braces around the macro content.
With this change, [your code compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16e66f658546b9f21551b16af8ebdd2d).